# статический виртуальный метод в C++ - возможно ли

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++, static, виртуальная-функция

Есть функция, которая одинаково обрабатывает данные для разных типов данных, чтобы не плодить лишнего кода решил обойтись шаблонами, где в качестве класса передавать класс с нужными наборами методов.

При этом, для каждого типа нужны будут свои методы.

В итоге получается следующий код (упрощённый):

```
template <class IExtractor>
bool MyFunc(...)
{
   return IExtractor::size();
}
```

И думал сделать следующим `IExtractor` универсальным следующим образом:

```
class IBaseExtractor
{
    public:
        static virtual int size() const = 0;
};

class CExtractor1: public IBaseextractor
{
    public:
        static int size() const {return 1;}
};

class CExtractor2: public IBaseextractor
{
    public:
        static int size() const {return 10;}
};

const bool res1 = MyFunc<CExtractor1>();
const bool res1 = MyFunc<CExtractor2>();
```

Но похоже в C++ виртуальный статический метод сделать нельзя.
Или я что-то не так делаю, можно ли как-то это обойти?

**P.S.**

Я понимаю, что можно было бы просто слепить 2 класса `CExtractor1` и `CExtractor2`, но хотелось бы сделать более красиво, т.е. явно показать на уровне компиляции какие методы нужны.

**P.P.S.**

Чтобы не удваивать код (что происходит при шаблонах) можно было бы член класса передавать как один из параметров функции, но это тоже немного криво, поскольку мне не нужен экземпляр класса, нужен только свой набор методов.

Хотя если бы такое понадобилось, то пришлось бы наверное использовать экземпляр класса как параметр, хотя мне кажется, это криво и лучше было бы отойти от этого.

Comment: Нет, виртуальный метод не может быть статическим. Что-то подобное вы можете реализовать "вручную", через указатели на функции, но не через встроенную языковую виртуальность.

Comment: @Zhihar похоже Вы ищите [CRTP](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/06/26/crtp_demystified.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем Вам вообще нужно использовать наследование? Для Вашего примера все и так будет прекрасно работать:

Extractors (я не знаю, что они должны делать на самом деле, поэтому, так же как и Вы, просто возвращаю некоторое целочисленное значение):

```
struct ExtractorA
{
    static auto size() -> unsigned { return 0x0A; }
};

struct ExtractorB
{
    static auto size() -> unsigned { return 0x0B; }
};
```

Шаблон функции:

```
template<typename Extractor>
inline auto extract() -> unsigned
{
    return Extractor::size();
}
```

Любой класс, который имеет static функцию size, которая возвращает значение типа `unsigned`[*], может быть параметром шаблона.

Пример:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    std::cout << "A = " << extract<ExtractorA>() << '\n'
              << "B = " << extract<ExtractorB>() << std::endl;
}
```

Если у Вас возникнет необходимость в наложении ограничения на тип, который выступает в качестве параметра шаблона, можно определить соответствующий концепт:

```
template<typename T>
concept Extractor = std::is_base_of_v<IExtractor, T>;
```

*Пояснение: мы требуем, чтобы тип экстрактора был классом унаследованным от `IExtractor`. Привел в качестве примера, в данном контексте не вижу смысла в этом ограничении.*

И непосредственно "наложить ограничение" на шаблон `extract`:

```
template<typename E> requires Extractor<E>
inline auto extract() -> std::size_t
{
    return E::size();
}
```

[*] - или то, что может быть приведено к `unsigned`.